# Как сразу выставить звук <audio> на определенный уровень?

Tags: html

Сайт с воспроизведением потока радио.

Проблема: при запуске звука ***нажатие на кнопку "эфир"***,
воспроизведение начинается со **100%** громкости, что не очень удобно.

Можно ли подправить, чтобы с 50% начинался?

```html
<audio id='player' src='http://бла-бла.mp3' />
<div style='position:absolute;  top:154px;  left:0px;  z-index:11;     width:104px;     line-height:98px;'>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).play()'>Эфир</button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).pause()'>Стоп</button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).volume+=0.1'><font size="+3">+</font></button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).volume-=0.1'><font size="+3">—</font></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87679/discussion-on-question-by-------audio--).

Answer (score 1):

Сразу выставить звук на определенный уровень `myVid.volume = 0.1;`

```js
var myVid = document.getElementById('player');
myVid.volume = 0.1;
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952238/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb"></audio>
<div style="position:absolute;  top:154px;  left:0px;  z-index:11;     width:104px;     line-height:98px;">
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Эфир</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Стоп</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">+</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Для получени 50%-й громкости потребуется соответственно установить **myVid.volume = 0.5;**